# Leading slash when sending request from nginx to squid

Tags: nginx, web-server, proxy, squid, proxypass

I am facing a weird situation. I want to load a webpage sitting behind Nginx. So I proxy pass a webpage request to `squid` as shown below in the snippet:

```
            location /about-me/yellow {
                    proxy_pass http://@squid/http://my-site.example.com/?nu=1&l=2;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_set_header Request-URI $request_uri;
                    proxy_redirect off;
            }
```

When the URL `/about-me/yellow` is hit the request is forwarded to `squid` but the request received is `/http://my-site.example.com/?nu=1&l=2` i.e. with a leading forward slash. Why does this happen? The error that I get is `INVALID_URI`. What is it that I am missing? Here is my complete Nginx configuration.

```
   upstream @squid {
     server x.x.x.x:3128;
   }

    server {
            root /public/; ## <-- Your only path reference.
            index index.php;
            server_name preprod.mygov.in;
            listen 83;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;preload";
            add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'no-referrer-when-downgrade';
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
            ### Disable HTTP Methods
            if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ )
            {
            return 405;
            }

            # Enable compression, this will help if you have for instance advagg module
            # by serving Gzip versions of the files.
            gzip_static on;

            location ~ ^/s3/files/styles/ {
                    try_files $uri @rewrite;
            }

            location = /favicon.ico {
                    log_not_found off;
                    access_log off;
            }

            location = /robots.txt {
                    allow all;
                    log_not_found off;
                    access_log off;
            }


            location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
                    allow 10.0.0.0/8;
                    deny all;
            }
            location ~* ^.+(\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|/Entries.*|/Repository|/Root|/Tag|/Template)$ {
                    deny all;
            }

            location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
                    return 403;
            }

            location ~ ^/sites/(.+)\.(phtml|pl|py|jsp|asp|aspx|shtml|htm|sh|cgi|exe) {
                    deny all;
            }

            location ~ ^/sites/(.+)\.php$ {
                    deny all;
            }

            # No no for private
            location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
                    return 403;
            }

            # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
            # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
            # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
            location ~ (^|/)\. {
                    return 403;
            }

            location / {
                    # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
                    try_files $uri @rewrite;
            }

            
            location ~ ^/s3/files/styles/ {
                    try_files $uri @rewrite;
            }


            location @rewrite {
                    # You have 2 options here
                    # For D7 and above:
                    # Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
                    rewrite ^ /index.php;
                    # For Drupal 6 and bwlow:
                    # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
                    # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
                    #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
            }

            fastcgi_connect_timeout 200;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 200;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 200;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                    #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            }


            location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
                    try_files $uri @rewrite;
            }

            location ~* \.(css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                    expires max;
                    log_not_found off;
            }

            location ~* \.(js|json)$ {
                    expires 1d;
                    log_not_found off;
            }

            location ~* \.(svg|woff|woff2)$ {
                    expires 30d;
                    log_not_found off;
            }

            location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {

                    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

            }    

            location /about-me/yellow {
                    proxy_pass http://@squid/http://my-site.example.com/?wid=675&lang=bn;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_set_header Request-URI $request_uri;
                    proxy_redirect off;
            }


    }
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Is this not the correct way to forward the request to squid? Anything that I am missing?

Comment: A path of an URL always starts with a forward slash, there's nothing strange about that.  But what are the scheme (http:) and the host (//my-site.example.com) doing there?  That's what the headers should be used for (as you do for Host).

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Could you recommend what would then be the correct way of calling squid?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Have updated the error screenshot

Comment: proxy_pass http://@squid/?nu=1&l=2;

Comment: Why do you put Nginx in front of Squid?   Is there something Squid cannot handle?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille If I do `proxy_pass http://@squid/?nu=1&l=2;`, how would the request be forwarded to `http://my-site.example.com`?

Comment: Squid will respect the Host header, if it respects HTTP 1.1. (since v. 3.2, yours seems to be 3.5).

Comment: So the request will be sent from `http://my.custom.ip/about-me/yellow` and has to be forwarded to `my-site.example.com` with query params `?wid=675&lang=bn` In this case how would squid know about `my-site.example.com`? @GerardH.Pille

Comment: @GerardH.Pille .

Comment: There's nobody here but us chickens, don't bother about the @g...   Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location /about-me/yellow {
    proxy_pass http://@squid/?wid=675&lang=bn;
    proxy_set_header Host "my-site.example.com";
    ...
```

I would expect the first line of your squid configuration to contain

```
http_port 3128 accel defaultsite=my-site.example.com
```

Comment: This is the log generated  at squid with the configuration I used earlier `1594703996.079      0 10.248.155.152 TAG_NONE/400 385 HEAD /http://my-site-example.com - HIER_NONE/- text/html` .. as you could see it has a leading forward slash

Comment: I want to understand what is wrong with the above configuration.

Comment: The URL in your configuration was wrong.  You can't have two methods and two hostnames.  http ://x.y.z/http: //a.b.c/... is invalid.

Comment: Are you going to try my solution?

Comment: Yes, but won't be able to do this right away as I cannot log in to the system because of some issue with my VPN

Comment: So I was thinking of communicating this over an email so that they can test it if they are able to connect. Thus asked the reason.

Comment: Don't you have a PC at your disposal?  You could try this on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Okay, let me try installing squid locally then. Have Nginx but do not have squid installed.

Comment: It is working now using the config you suggested. Had to add `vhost` and `allow-true` in squid. Any idea what does `vhost` and `allow-true` mean? I added this in squid `http_port 3128 host allow-true`

Comment: "vhost for Squid-3.1 or older enables HTTP/1.1 domain based virtual hosting support. Omit this option for Squid-3.2 or later versions."  Please read https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/VirtualHosting

Comment: I do not find "host" nor "allow-true"  in the squid documentation for http_port.